# Set Value on Webpage without using ID (as ID changes)

Tags: c#, html, getelementbyid, setvalue

I would like to set a value on a webpage using windows application form and using GetElementById and
   SetAttribute("value", desiredValue)
I have created a command list which navigates through the webpage and puts in values:

```
currentCommands.Enqueue(new Command("setvalue", "45", 
"setPublishMin"));
```

whereas "setPublishMin" links to the ID of the textbox on the wepage via a commandHandler class and csv file
The ID looks like this

id="WebpageAdminTheme_ComponentList_ctl02_wtExpandableInnerBlock_wtExpandableSe
    ction__Sets"]

Once I have filled in the textbox and add select another textbox in which I want to pass different values the ID will be the same apart from "*ctl02*" changing to "*ctl04*" etc. in the ID. 
So I was wondering if there is an easier way to pass over the values than by using IDs

Comment: What are the elements you are working with? BTW, is it ASP.NET?

Comment: Could give it a class and use that, not the best way but should work.

Comment: I have edited the question.Hope it is better now

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [ClientIdMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<asp:ContentID="content"ContentPlaceHolderID="content"runat="server"ClientIDMode="Static" >    
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"ID="txtName"ClientIDMode="Static" />        
</asp:Content>
```

Static 
This option forces the control’s ClientID to use its ID value directly. No naming container naming at all is applied and you end up with clean client ids:

```
<inputname="ctl00$content$txtName"type="text"id="txtName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the same values for all inputs from "ctl02" to "ctl04", then you can achieve this by class also. Give the same class to all the controls and set the value using the class.

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].setAttribute("value", "foo");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the values are varying for different inputs

Comment: Are you using Asp.net? Can you please share some sample code?

Comment: I'm using a windows application form. I have also edited the post. I hope it makes a bit more sense now